# I can't vertically align to bottom a font size of several em values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want G to stick to the bottom of it's parent. (G to the bottom of the white background).

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.staff {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.staff span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.008em;
}

.clef {
background: pink;
  font-size: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: 'bottom';
}
```

```html
<div class='staff'>
<span class='clef'>G</span>
</div>
```

I also tried `display: flex; align-items: flex-end;` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.staff {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  
}

.staff span {
}

.clef {
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  font-size: 1.008em;
  background: pink;
  line-height: 0.7;
  /* font-size: 0.25em; */
  vertical-align: "bottom";
}
```

```html
<div class='staff'>
<span class='clef'>Good</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do

Comment: if you want align it to left also, you can use `padding-left: 0;` in **.staff{}** class

Comment: This helped me not to mix bottom or nested font-sizes. So I got it working, If you provide some explanation or at least give some reference to what is going on, I will accept this as an answer

Comment: Though the text is centered on the staff as I would have liked, it seems not to have aligned to the bottom, not that it was a necessity. Because text is aligned on the staff as I wanted with this technique.

Comment: Well I reduced the height between the lines. you can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). to align it properly you can reduce the value of `line-height` as you want

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, I was wondering how you lowered the character and how I couldn't. doesn't explain why vertical align doesn't work though.